# How to convert a HP ProLiant DL140 G3 rackmount server to a tower?

Tags: networking

I recently bought a HP ProLiant DL140 G3 Server server and want to convert it to a tower case.

I am looking at [HENBRO SR20969-CO](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811123127). Before I spend cash, what are some of the potential problems I might run into converting it?

Comment: The DL140 is not a blade server.  It's a 1U size rackmount server.  Blade servers are something quite different, where multiple server units are kept within a large single mother rackmount unit.

Comment: I hate to ask but *why*? Is it as a result of noise, need to have better, more accessible expantion slots or other reasons? The 'best' answer would depend on all these things

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I suspect it is simply because rack equipment without a rack case is unwieldy and awkward to situate.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am going to be using this at home and dont have a space for a rack.

Comment: Most "can I" questions are based on your skill set, depending on what they are, the answer could be Yes or No. I can make your project work, but others may not have the skills to pull it off. I edited your question to clear things up.

Comment: @Moab While you're editing, you can remove the self-degradation as well ;)

Comment: @slhck I saved that for you. ;-o

Answer (score 3):

Most caes that you purchase will support ATX format motherboards (or Micro-ATX or mini-ATX etc).

The motherboard in the DL140 is not a standard ATX format.  There are several things that make putting it in a standard case difficult.

1. The backpanel (where usb etc connections are) is wide and flat - single layer, as opposed to two layer.
2. Screw connections are likely to not align with the positions in the case
3. The connector to the disks/backplane looks like it is solid, and there don't appear to be any sata connectors on the motherboard to avoid using them, so you are going to have difficulties mounting the disks and running cables to the connectors.

Basically, it isn't going to fit right.  I imagine your main issue is with the noise, so perhaps the best approach would be to mount the server with the lid off, inside a custom case, where you can house a standard PSU and system fans.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through the hassle of doing that, I would recommend you get a rack case and convert to rack equipment, as it is much neater and saves space, once you have more than a couple of computers.

I actually do the opposite and put pedestal servers into Antec rackmount cases, as pedestal servers are usually cheaper, and nearly always a lot quieter (eg. I have done this with the HP ProLiant ML110 G5, ML115 G5, and ML350 G6).

You can get small rack units of around 10U (the very small ones are not deep enough for servers, only networking equipment) with glass doors and veneered top surfaces, and even insulation padding, so they can fit into a home or office very nicely.

[image: Office rack case]

You can even make a rack case from a cheap 'Lack' coffee table from IKEA.  [Here](http://wiki.eth-0.nl/index.php/LackRack) is a website about that.

[image: Lack rack]